# How to bind three different input using ngModel in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 different ngModel which is being displayed sequentially in modal window so `CURRENT_TEXT` and `ALLERGY_DETAILS` always get same value when i finish changes , is there better way to acheive this task using `ngModel` or i am missing something ?

app.component.html

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="showSubQuestions">
    <div  *ngFor="let option of singleQuestion.answerOption">
    <div *ngFor="let sub of option.subQuestion">
        <label for="subQuestionsInput">{{sub.questionText}}</label>
        <input type="subQuestionsInput" class="form-control"  name="allerdydetail" placeholder="answerText" [(ngModel)]="ALLERGY_DETAILS.answerText">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="showSubQuestionsCommon">
    <div  *ngFor="let option of singleQuestion.answerOption">
        <div *ngFor="let sub of option.subQuestion">
        <label for="subQuestionsCommon">{{sub.questionText}}</label>
        <input type="subQuestionsCommon" class="form-control"  name="currentText" placeholder="Text" [(ngModel)]="CURRENT_TEXT.answerText">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="showSubQuestionsQues"> 
<div  *ngFor="let option of singleQuestion.answerOption">
    <div *ngFor="let sub of option.subQuestion">
        <div *ngFor="let ques of sub.question; let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">
            <label for="subQuestionsInput">{{ques.questionText}}</label>
            <!-- <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ques.question[i]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"> -->
            <input type="subQuestionsInput" class="form-control" *ngIf= "ques.answerType === 'TEXT_NUMBER'" name="TEXT_NUMBER" placeholder="Enter Dose amount Left"  [(ngModel)]="TEXT_NUMBER.answerText">
            <input type="subQuestionsInput" class="form-control" *ngIf= "ques.answerType === 'TEXT_DATE'" name="TEXT_DATE" placeholder="Enter Next Dose Date" [(ngModel)]="TEXT_DATE.answerText"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { EventService} from './format-questions/format-questions.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('closeBtn', {static: false}) closeBtn: ElementRef;
  data: any;
  questions: any[] = [];
  singleQuestion: any[] = [];
  showSaveButton: boolean = false;
  showNextButton: boolean = true;
  showSubQuestions: boolean = false;
  currentSelectedItem: any;
  questionsOptionSelected: boolean = false;
  showSubQuestionsQues: boolean = false;
  questionsArray: any =[];
  subQuestionsAnswertext: any = [];
  TEXT_DATE: any;
  TEXT_NUMBER: any;
  CURRENT_TEXT: any;
  ALLERGY_DETAILS: any;
  showSubQuestionsCommon: boolean = false;

  constructor(private dataService:ApiService, private eventService:EventService) {
    this.questions = this.dataService.getData();
      this.TEXT_DATE = {
        "answerOptionId": 0,
        "answerText": "",
        "answerOptionId2": 0
    };
      this.TEXT_NUMBER = {
        "answerOptionId": 0,
        "answerText": "",
        "answerOptionId2": 0
    };
      this.CURRENT_TEXT =  {
        "answerOptionId": 0,
        "answerText": "",
        "answerOptionId2": 0
    };
      this.ALLERGY_DETAILS = {
        "answerOptionId": 0,
        "answerText": "",
        "answerOptionId2": 0
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: @DanielHabenicht any example with above code new to angular

Answer (score 0):

Just use reactive-forms as suggested in the comment above, 
in ur component create a new **ALLERGY_DETAILS** formControl:

**component.ts**

```
ALLERGY_DETAILS: FormControl = new FormControl('',Validators.required)
// remove the second parameter in case the value is not required
// to get the input value use 
this.ALLERGY_DETAILS.value;
```

then in HTML template link the input element with the controller:

**component.html**

```
<input type="subQuestionsInput" class="form-control"
  name="allerdydetail" placeholder="answerText" 
  [formControl]="ALLERGY_DETAILS">
```

finally import ReactiveFormsModule in ur app.module.ts

Comment: I tried exactly you explained it works for `ALLERGY_DETAILS` , `CURRENT_TEXT` always coming as empty string and `TEXT_NUMBER` and `TEXT_DATE` both have same values any idea ?

Comment: Did u remove the **[(ngModel)]** from `CURRENT_TEXT` ?,
also for `NUMBER, DATE` u probably link two different inputs to the same controller

Comment: Yes ngModel is removed from the inputs , all of these are in one component , what do you mean by two different inputs to same controller these all are in the single ‘form’

Comment: asked another question using FormGroup if you can help still trying to find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990604/how-to-dynamically-add-inputs-value-to-angular-component

Comment: if u want to split ur form to small FormGroups(cause u have *ngFor , use FormArray of FormGroups and inside each group create needed formControls ,
then to link input tag to the controller u can do smth like this :
__formarray[i].controls['controlerName']__